# Deleting data when the bot leaves the channel in telegram bot py

Tags: python, bots, telegram

i have this code:

```
def callback_func(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    left_chat_member = update.effective_message.left_chat_member

    if left_chat_member and left_chat_member.id == context.bot.id:
        # Remove all data related to the channel from JSON files
        remove_channel_data_from_json(chat_id)

def remove_channel_data_from_json(channel_id):
    # List of files that need the channel ID removed
    files_to_remove = ['message.json', 'settings.json', 'channel.json']

    # Remove channel data from other files
    for file_name in files_to_remove:
        try:
            with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)

            if str(channel_id) in data:
                del data[str(channel_id)]

            with open(file_name, 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(data, json_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

and

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.left_chat_member, callback_func))
```

my question is:
How do you perform the action when a bot leaves the channel?
Because right now, when the bot is removed from the channel, it doesn't work and nothing happens.